# Prepositional phrases next to adjectives

Tags: phrases, adjectives, prepositional-phrases

-The boy *akin* **to an impassioned bard** recited his stories

-The girl *similar* **to him** stood still.

These adjectives (italicized) and others similar are always placed next to a prepositional phrase (bolded) of some sort. Do the adjective + prepositional phrase make an adjective phrase? And what is the prepositional phrase, by itself, modifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those adjectives and their preposition phrase complements (they are allowed by a certain subset of adjectives) do form adjective phrases. These adjective phrases are modifiers in noun phrases in your examples where they modify the head nouns *boy* and *girl*.

That they are part of adjective phrases is supported by the fact that these adjective prhases can be used predicatively:

> He described the boy as akin to an impassioned bard.
>
> She was similar to him.

Note that the adjectives in question are not always placed next to preposition phrases - that is, they do not always require a preposition phrase complement.

> The dog and fox are closely akin. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/akin))
>
> no two animal habitats are exactly similar ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/similar))